# How can I hide these bones? They are always visible

Tags: rigging, bones

They are visible on all modes and all shadings. H or alt+H doesn't hide them.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Try selecting the armature, and under Object Data Properties > Viewport Display. Uncheck "In front".

[image]